# What exactly does the [x](y) operator do?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

My goal is to evaluate images pixel by pixel. Instead of:

```
count = 0
for x in range(w):
  for y in range(h):
    pixel_1, pixel_2 = img_1[x, y], img_2[x, y]
      if pixel_1 == 0 and pixel_2 == 0:
        count += 1
```

I had seen a way to do this by using the [] and () operators:

```
sum((img_1 == 0)[img_2 == 0])
```

I am trying to understand what this means. I've been trying to search for it, but I don't know the proper terms to describe it. I am also trying to apply it to three images at once:

```
sum((img_1 == 0)[img_2 == 0 and img_3 == 0])
```

But that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A lot is happening on this line:

```py
sum((img_1 == 0)[img_2 == 0])
```

first, `img_1 == 0` is an operation that returns a numpy array of 1's where `imp_1` is not zero, else 0. Try to print it to have a look. This array does have the save size as `img_1`. The operation in the brackets is basically the same operation with img_2.

Here, there are 1's (equivalent to `True`) where there are 0's in `a1`:

```
a1 = np.arange(2*3).reshape(2, 3)
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5]])

a1 == 0
# array([[ True, False, False],
#        [False, False, False]])
```

**The parenthesis around `img_1 == 0` are only here so that the following indexing operation —materialized by the brackets— apply to the result of `img_1 == 0` rather than to the `0` number.**. It is not an operation but a mean to group and give priority to some operations (see @hpaulj comment).

The last operation involved —the one materialized by the brackets— is an indexing operation. First note that `(img_1 == 0)` and `img_2 == 0` are the same size (considering that both images are the same size). **This operation retrieves only the elements from `(img_1 == 0)` where there are 0's `in img_2`.** This "selects" elements from an array according to the index specified inside the brackets.

Here there are three 1's in `a` at different location. The operation retrieves only the elements in `a` where `a == 1` is true, so it returns the three ones:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [3, 1, 4]])
a[a == 1]
# array([1, 1, 1])
```

This summing operation is not the most understandable form, you can use this one for your 3-image case:

```py
((img1 == 0) & (img2 == 0) & (img3 == 0)).sum()
```

This reads pretty well: "creates a numpy array of 1's and 0's containing 1's where there are 0's in imag1 AND there are 0's in img2 AND ..., then sum this array".

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot! When I had printed img_1 == 0 I did notice that it the resulting array had the same dimensions (ndim = 2), and (img_1 == 0)[img_2 == 0] had an array of 1 dimension. So just to confirm, (img_1)[img_2] is the dot product of img_1 and img_2?

Comment: I was also wondering why my iterative method was returning a different sum than the parenthesis/bracket notation. It makes sense that if [img_1 == 0](img_2 == 0) is the dot product, then it would be returning a smaller sum because it's also evaluating True & False == False for the answer (if I'm understanding correctly).

Comment: @cristina, `(x)[y]` is not a 'dot' product.  The `()` just group an action, giving it priority.  the `[]` is an indexing operation.  Sooner or later you need to read up on `numpy` indexing.  `dot` product (usually) refers to a mathematical multiplication and summation.  `numpy` has a `np.dot` and `@` to do that.